# Java Processbuilder: GraphicsMagick/imagemagick convert hangs

Tags: processbuilder, amazon-emr, imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick

The below command hangs in Java processbuilder whereas the same command produce expected result in command line.

gm convert -debug all -log %u %m:%l %e -limit Disk 5GB -limit memory 1GB -limit map 1GB -limit pixels 50MB -limit Threads 1 inputfile -quality 82 -size 700x500 -scale 700x500> jpg:out

when i check the top command for the task it gives below information

Tasks:   1 total,   0 running,   1 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.3%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 99.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  30827392k total,  7131008k used, 23696384k free,   126288k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,  4447716k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
18260 yarn      20   0  165m 9148 5436 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 gm

From the above information, the task went to sleep after 02 milliseconds.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about trying a very simple command gm convert input -scale 700x500 jpg:out and then building on it if it works?

Comment: i tried it already not helpful though.

Comment: Try making the input and output file type explicit by using a recognised extension. Try also removing  the `-size 700x500` as it does nothing.

Comment: i tried the below and the result is same. Task has been sleeping.
convert -debug all -log %u %m:%l %e /tmp/test_2017-06-13T08:09:33.584Z_ftwid.jpg -quality 82 -scale 700x500 jpg.jpg

Comment: surprisingly it works when i remove -debug and -log